# ng-bootstrap 10.0.0 dropdown menu autoclose outside not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

here my angular version 12 and i am using ng-bootstrap 10.0.0
i am getting problem actually when i am clicking on scrollbar to move dropdown is get closed  so i found we can use `autoClose="outside"` , but it is not working `[autoClose]="false/true"` is working but not `outside` property is working it getting closed when we are clicking inside only , bootstrap version is 5.1.0

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top-start" class="btn-group d-inline-block" [autoClose]="'outside'" #drp="ngbDropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-secondary" id="numberOfPages" ngbDropdownToggle>goto</button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="numberOfPages" class="dropdown-list  dropdown-menu-dark">
                <div id="top-startBtnDrp" style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
                    <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'active':currentPage==1+i}"
                        *ngFor="let item of dataArr,let i=index" ngbDropdownItem>{{1+i}}/button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top-start" class="btn-group d-inline-block" [autoClose]="'outside'" #drp="ngbDropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-secondary" id="numberOfPages" ngbDropdownToggle>goto</button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="numberOfPages" class="dropdown-list  dropdown-menu-dark">
                <div id="top-startBtnDrp" style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
                    <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'active':currentPage==1+i}"
                        *ngFor="let item of dataArr,let i=index" ngbDropdownItem>{{1+i}}/button>
                </div>
            </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Try above code have some syntax error in your code so that might be work.

Comment: yeah that was mistakenly removed after it also it is not working

Comment: i made this in my side project there it is working , but on my working area it is not not getting why ,  how can i debug this !!

Comment: Yeah i checked i place breakpoint  in source of dropdown and found why when i am placing breakpoint it is not closing and when i am adding breakpoint then it get closed , deep problem with ngbDropdown